# Android widget doesn't work immediatelly after update

Tags: android, widget

I have problem with android widget(it shows battery state). If You have this widget on home screen and you will update it from android market there is a problem with working. Widget doesn't work until battery state will not change. I don't know how to fix it. Is there any function, which is started (after installation of new version ) in appwidgetprovider or service?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to restart the program launcher to get a widget to update after installing it from Market.

1. Go to Settings → Apps → Running.
2. Choose "Launcher" (this may be named differently depending on your version of Android; you may also have to touch "Show Cached Processes" to see it).
3. Touch "Stop".
4. Now touch the Home button again, and go back to your widget chooser
   (pre-Android 4.0, long-touch the home screen; Android 4.0+, touch
   the application launcher button in the middle of the bar and select
   the Widgets tab).
5. You should now see the widget. Add it to your home screen as normal.

Comment: I asked about how to refresh widget after update as developer. I need to change code of my app

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. What you wrote seemed to describe a common user-side problem. So you're saying that if your widget is updated in market, the user can accept and install the update, but the old widget will continue to run? Does this continue after a Launcher restart and an Android reboot?

Comment: No. When user installs new version, old version stops running and new is running on old's place after few minutes, when battery state changes. I want it to run new version just after user will install it, not after battery state change

Comment: Hi, did you find solution to your problem?